# Rvest/ XPath returning funky column name - why and how can I avoid this?

Tags: xpath, rvest

I am trying to parse a wikipedia table and it returns a strange column name. I believe this is because of the `style` node, or am I doing something wrong? Can I somehow write an XPath to avoid the `style` node?

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_Winter_Olympics" %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_element(xpath = "//*[@id='mw-content-text']/div[1]/table[10]") %>% 
  html_table()
```

The second column name I get is `.mw-parser-output .tooltip-dotted{border-bottom:1px dotted;cursor:help}NOC` while it should just be `NOC`

Comment: Your XPath just points to the table. 
If you want the xpath to the text()-node of the second column, you would need:
`//*[@id='mw-content-text']/div[1]/table[10]/thead/tr/th[2]/text()`

Comment: I want the whole table, but when I use html_table I end up with a strange column name.

Comment: So not a xpath issue but a rvest html_table issue...

Comment: likely inline css. See if can remove with regex or xml lib before passing any html to html_table. There will be some R solutions on this site.